# ClassFormatError when invoking defineClass with bytes read using JarInputStream read method

Tags: java, classloader

I am using the following method to read bytes from jar entries (containing class files only). There is no jar file inside the jar.

```
private List<byte[]> readFromJarFile(File cp) 
{
    List<byte[]> cbytes = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    try 
    {
        java.util.jar.JarInputStream jin = new java.util.jar.JarInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(cp));
        java.util.jar.JarEntry je = jin.getNextJarEntry();
        while (je != null)
        {
            if (!je.isDirectory() && je.toString().endsWith(".class")) 
            {
                //assume class file size < Integer.MAX_VALUE
                System.out.printf("readFromJarFile: jar entry name %s ...%n",je.toString());
                byte[] cbyte = new byte[(int) je.getSize()];
                jin.read(cbyte,0,(int) je.getSize());
                cbytes.add(cbyte);
            }
            je = jin.getNextJarEntry();
        }
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ie)
    {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cbytes;
}
```

Now when I am calling defineClass with a byte array returned from the above method following exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 0 in class file <Unknown>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:465)
at san.tool.JPAEntityProcessor$JPAClassLoader.loadClass(JPAEntityProcessor.java:34)
at san.tool.JPAEntityProcessor.processJPAEntities(JPAEntityProcessor.java:49)
at san.tool.JPAEntityProcessorTest.testWithJarFile(JPAEntityProcessorTest.java:40)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at
```

I searched this site and all other forums on the internet but couldn't find an answer. I am looking forward to some insights from the members here.

Thanks and regards
Santanu

Comment: Interesting. May you post a zip with a basic test case with such a jar file ?

Comment: Ok I shall post a zip of my code along with the jar file. But am quite new here so not sure how to post a zip file.

Answer (score 4):

```
jin.read(cbyte,0,(int) je.getSize());
```

It is not guaranteed that `read` method will read `je.getSize()` bytes into buffer. Instead, it returns count of bytes actually read. You need to wrap read attempts into loop and read until buffer filled.

Something like this:

```
int len = (int) je.getSize();
int offset = 0;
int read;
while ((read = jin.read(cbyte, offset, len - offset)) > 0) {
    offset += read;
}
```

*UPD* After a year I realized, that my original example will stuck after reading whole stream. And later "fixed" version will not actually enter the loop. So, here is short, correct and tested version.

Comment: I assume the while-loop is required if my read buffer size is less than the size of the entry (or a file). Where am I making the mistake in assuming this? Why this loop is required even if the entry size and my read buffer size are same?

Comment: No, in my example we filling buffer with parts of received data, assuming the buffer big enough to hold all data. If buffer is filled, but data is still available, it will loop forever. It is general contract of [`read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) method. You request it to fill buffer, and it fills it with current available data, but no more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and actually the correct way to do it is:

```
int read = 0;
int len = (int) je.getSize();
int offset = 0;
do {
    read = jin.read(cbyte, offset, len - offset);
    offset += read;
} while (read > 0);
```

this I tested and works. Note that in the answer above it will never enter the loop because `read` is initialized to zero.